# Excel Userform - Ghost controls getting added

Tags: excel, vba

I manually add controls (Labels) to a Userform in design mode.

I then select some/all of them, right-click on the Userform and choose the Make Same Size option. When I click on height, the controls become of the same height. But ghost Labels are getting added. Why are new labels getting added and how do I prevent them?

Is there someway to remove labels added during design time.

Comment: Are you sure that people will be able to replicate this ? See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am finding it hard to put into words what is happening.  I agree that it will be difficult for others to replicate.